# How to search for location and display results with MapKit Swift 4

Tags: mapkit, swift4

I am developing an application with Swift 4 (Xcode 9.2).

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/). I get my location  [my location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9oCO.png) but when I search for a place, the map was hidden: [Search a place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxV20.png) and it reappear just when I delete all what I write in the search bar as the original one(just My location).

Here is my code :

```
protocol HandleMapSearch: class {
  func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var selectedPin: MKPlacemark?
var resultSearchController: UISearchController!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestLocation()
    let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
    resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable as UISearchResultsUpdating
    let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
    navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
    resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
    locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView
    locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self

}

@objc func getDirections(){
    guard let selectedPin = selectedPin else { return }
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

extension ViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error:: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if locations.first != nil {
            print("location:: (location)")
        }

    }
       }
 extension ViewController: HandleMapSearch {

func dropPinZoomIn(placemark: MKPlacemark){
    // cache the pin
    selectedPin = placemark
    // clear existing pins
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
    annotation.title = placemark.name

    if let city = placemark.locality,
        let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
            annotation.subtitle = "\(city) \(state)"
    }

    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
   }

 }

 extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{

    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }
    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    }
    pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.orange
    pinView?.canShowCallout = true
    let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: smallSquare))
    //button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "car"), for: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.getDirections), for: .touchUpInside)
    pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button

    return pinView
   }
 }
```

and this is the LocationSearchTable  :

```
    class LocationSearchTable: UITableViewController {


    weak var handleMapSearchDelegate: HandleMapSearch?
    var matchingItems: [MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView?


    func parseAddress(selectedItem:MKPlacemark) -> String {

        // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
        let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil &&
                            selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""

        // put a comma between street and city/state
        let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) &&
                    (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""

        // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
        let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil &&
                            selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""

        let addressLine = String(
            format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
            // street number
            selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
            firstSpace,
            // street name
            selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
            comma,
            // city
            selectedItem.locality ?? "",
            secondSpace,
            // state
            selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
        )

        return addressLine
      }
    }

    extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
     func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    }


    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }

        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

        search.start { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
         }
        }
      }
extension LocationSearchTable {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = parseAddress(selectedItem: selectedItem)
        return cell
     }
    }
   extension LocationSearchTable {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        handleMapSearchDelegate?.dropPinZoomIn(placemark: selectedItem)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Please I need your help to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you test in the device?

Comment: Yes,I test with my iPhone 5s.

Comment: Can you please show your current code?

Comment: I edit my question by putting the hole code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong delegate func **updateSearchResultsForSearchController**. Use the following code.

```
extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }

        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

        search.start { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you like to search the city only, you can use **locality** only. See the example below.Otherwise, keep your code intact.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.locality
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "" //parseAddress(selectedItem: selectedItem)
        return cell
    }
```

[EDIT 1]

Another deprecated delegate needs to be changed for getting direction:

```
extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{

        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }
        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        }
        pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.orange
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true
        let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: smallSquare))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "car"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.getDirections), for: .touchUpInside)
        pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button

        return pinView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,this solves the issue. But when I click on the annotation, I  can't get the direction to the destination.